How do I use Bitlocker on a mapped drive?
The drive is a usb attached to my router and has been mapped as a drive.
It shows and works fine from explorer.
But when I open Bitlocker from control panel I cannot see the drive
Thanks :-)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Bitlocker is only applicable to local drives. Yours is a network share.

You can encrypt individual files on a network drive, but you cannot encrypt the full volume of a network drive from a remote computer. If the host (server the drive is physically connected to) can encrypt, it can encrypt the complete drive, but a router is unlikely to support this.

You don't, because there is no drive that BitLocker on your PC could access.
BitLocker works at disk-sector level, but a mapped network drive does not have those; the SMB protocol deals with individual files and doesn't expose the raw disk. (So it's literally more like a folder that has its own drive letter, than an actual "drive".)
All actual filesystem and disk access is handled by the SMB server (your router), so if any disk-level encryption was used, it would also need to be configured on the server. A different kind of device could do that; e.g. a RPi-like system could be configured to share a LUKS (or even BitLocker) encrypted disk through the same SMB. (But the unlock key would need to be either stored on the server – so if someone stole both, they could unlock it anyway – or re-entered manually via SSH every time the server was restarted.)
